# Java Gson does not catch exception

Tags: java, gson

My code is given below :

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = "{\"organization\":null}";
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject rootobj = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(json);

        User_Objects fillObj = new User_Objects();
        fillObj.setCommEmail(rootobj.get("organization").getAsString());

        request.setAttribute("reqObj", fillObj);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception>>>>>>>" + e);
    }
}
```

When i debug this project, it will not come on `System.out.println("Exception>>>>>>>" + e);`
While I have "organization" as null not String.

Comment: If you step through this code with a debugger, is the getAsString() line being reached?

Comment: @UserF40 When i debug it, it comes on line "fillObj.setCommEmail(rootobj.get("organization").getAsString());" then when i press F6(Step Over) it goes to the end "}"

Comment: In your IDE, you should be able to select/highlight rootobj.get("organization").getAsString() and evaluate just that, see if it returns an error.

Comment: @UserF40 when i select ctrl+shift+i it gives me error "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull
 at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:191)"

Comment: @I want to catch all Exception.

Comment: The catch Exception should catch UnsupportedOperationException, if you add a break point to the System.out.println, when you rerun, after the getStringLine is stepped over does it go there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125282/discussion-between-userf40-and-user3441151).